# Elastica multi_field setup

Tags: mapping, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm trying to use multi_field syntax of elasticsearch in combination with Elastica. I create an index and an mapping which looks like this:

```
$mapping->setProperties(array(
    'id'         => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => true),
    'title'      => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => true),
    'publisher'  => array('type' => 'multi_field', 'include_in_all' => TRUE, 'fields' => 
       array('publisherName' => array('type' => 'string', 'index' => 'analyzed'),
             'untouched'     => array('type' => 'string', 'index' => 'not_analyzed')
    )
));
```

So far, so good. I can run queries against the title field.

But when I try to query the field "publisher" in http://example.com:9200/_plugin/head/ I'm not able to select the field publisher or to create a structured query. I looks, that the field publisher is not in the index.

But I can build facets on publisher.untouched which works very well. Whats wrong in my mapping? I need to search for the publisher.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs on [multi_field mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-multi-field-type.html).  Looks like you need to set a default field by changing 'publisherName' to just 'publisher'.